# Rules based on absolute path + filename

Tags: vim, scripting

I work on a large code base that has various code styles (tabs vs spaces etc.).  For the spacing problem, I'd like to automate some vim settings based on the path of the file.  Ideally I'd like to do something like

```
if (absolute_path.match(".*/kernel")) then 
   use_tabs()
else if (abslute_path.match(".*/someuserspace_folder/*")) then
   use_spaces()
end
```

Googling on the subject has led me to create this Frankenstein:

```
function! SetIndentSpaces()
        set tabstop=4
        set shiftwidth=4
        set expandtab
        echo "Using spaces for indentation"
endfunction

function! SetIndentTabs()
        set tabstop=8
        set shiftwidth=8
        set noexpandtab
        echo "Using tabs for indentation"
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter,BufRead */kernel/*.\(c|h\) call SetIndentTabs() 
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead */userpace_code/*.\(cpp|c|h\) call SetIndentSpaces()
```

However, I don't see my triggers getting called.  I'm guessing that my regex is wrong, but I can't find any way validate it (read: I suck at vim).

Anyone spot something obvious in what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is escape the `|` with `\|`.

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead */kernel/*.\(c\|h\) call SetIndentTabs() 
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead */userpace_code/*.\(cpp\|c\|h\) call SetIndentSpaces()
```

Also you should add `set softtabstop=8` (or 4) to your indent functions. Normally you want tabstop, shiftwidth and softtabstop to be the same.

---

According to `:h file-pattern` (and Ingo Karkat) you should go with the following lines instead

```
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead */kernel/*.{c,h} call SetIndentTabs() 
autocmd BufEnter,BufRead */userpace_code/*.{cpp,c,h} call SetIndentSpaces()
```

The patterns used by the file-pattern matching

```
                            *file-pattern*
The pattern is interpreted like mostly used in file names:
    { } like \( \) in a |pattern|
    ,   inside { }: like \| in a |pattern|
```

Comment: That works; but where is that documented. `:h file-pattern` says one should use `*.{c,h}` (which works, too), but doesn't mention `\(...\|...\)`?!

Comment: If you never ever use `'softtabstop'`, it's alright to keep it at its default of `0`. But I agree that it's safer to set its value together with the other options.